# How to access "local" variable when a "global", "local" and "very local" variable exist having same name

Tags: c++, scope

```
int i = 1;
int main()
{
    int i = 2;
    {
        int i = 3;
        cout << ::i << endl;  //i want to print 2, neither 1 nor 3
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I want to print 2. By default, cout << i << endl; prints 3 and cout << ::i << endl; prints 1.

Comment: You can't.  There's a reason "shadowing" same-named variables like this is a bad idea.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need this functionality? Even if it is technically possible, this kind of code is messy and error-prone. I don't think it is ever recommended to name a local variable after a global variable with the intent of using the global variable. Just name them separately

Comment: @Michael Karpinski No specific reason. Just wanted to know if it is technically possible.

Comment: @DimChtz Im' using :: in this case as a "unary scope resolution operator"

Comment: ... and that's why `::i` evaluates to a different value than does `i` in the innermost block.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way to refer to a local name when it has been hidden by another local name in a nested scope (such as the `i` with value 2 by the `i` with the value 3). The best you can do is create a reference to it while it's still in scope:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 2;
    int& middle_i = i;
    {
        int i = 3;
        cout << middle_i << endl;  //will print 2
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, the actually correct solution is not to hide names you need to access, so rename one of the local `i` variables.

---

Since the question is also tagged `c`, be aware that C lacks both references and the scope resolution operator (`::`), so in C you're stuck with using a pointer (even worse than a reference in this regard), or following the "actually correct solution" even strongly and not hiding *any* names you intend to use.

Answer (score 1):

You may be misinterpreting the concept of scopes.

Local variables with the same name **always** have the priority.
It just doesn't make sense otherwise, how will the compiler know which variable you are referencing to?
It is considered bad practice to use variables with the same name within the same parent scope and it is evident why. Either reuse the same variable or write another function to be called.

You can create a pointer to access the outer variable and since there is an answer regarding C++ I will give an example in C

```
int i = 1;
int* p;
int main()
{
    int i = 2;
    p = &i;
    {
        int i = 3;
        // print *p
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity (correct me if I am wrong), was it necessary to declare pointer p outside main()? Would it make no difference if I write: int i = 2;
int* p = &i;
 within the main()

Comment: Sure, whatever suits you. You can declare the pointer inside main if you want. Some people would rather prefer that. Some people are against global variables.